# Find subsequence of length k with the largest product

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

**Language:** Python

Given an array of integers, return the subsequence of length `k` which has the largest possible product. If there is more than one valid subsequence that gives the same product, return the one with the largest sum of numbers.

Example 1

```
array = [-10, -3, 5, 6, -2]
k = 2
```

Output should be `[-10, -3]` ( *(-10) * (-3) = 30*, which is the largest product of the given numbers)

Example 2

```
array = [10, 3, 5, 6, 20]
k = 3
```

Output should be `[6, 10, 20]`, (*6 * 10 * 20 = 1200*)

Example 3

```
array = [1, -4, 3, -6, 7, 0]
k = 4
```

Output should be `[-6, -4, 3, 7]`  ( *(-6) * (-4) * 3 * 7  = 504*)

I've already tried the code

```
def find_k_prod(arr, k):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    current_prod = 1
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(k):
        current_prod *= arr[n-1-i]
        
    max_prod = current_prod
    for i in range(k):
        current_prod = (current_prod/arr[-(k-i)])*arr[i]
        max_prod = max(current_prod, max_prod)
    
    return max_prod
```

, but have no idea how to return the subsequence (not the product).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tell us what language you're working in, and show us the code you have so far. Not a link to a discussion page, but the actual code.

Comment: Hi! Great to become a part of the community, thanks for the suggestions, I'll edit the question

Comment: Naturally you have to keep track of which subsequence is responsible for the current value of `current_prod`.